# Where can I access PDO prepared statement templates

Tags: mysql, pdo

When you use mysqli or pdo prepared statments the sql is sent to the mysql server and stored as a template for further execution. My question is how do I view those templates in mysql?

Comment: I doubt you can. Out of curiousity, why would you want to?

Comment: The idea that is works via magic is not that appealing. Also it would be nice to see how many active templates I have on a server to optimize my code. There is a limit to how many templates can be stored and I would like to know if I get close to that limit.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that prepared statement only persists within a session?

Comment: It probably helps to think of them not as templates, but rather as temporarily pre-compiled statements that MySQL can reuse without much overhead _for the current connection_. I don't believe they are stored in any permanent way, only as session variables. Your means of keeping track of how many you have is as simple as counting up how many you have created in your application or session on the current connection. They are deallocated as soon as the connection closes.